# Как горизонтально и вертикально отразить матрицу

Tags: матрицы, php, циклы

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу! Как горизонтально и вертикально отразить матрицу, используя цикл `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Мог чего напутать, под рукой нет редактора

```
$matrix = array(
     array(1, 2, 3),       // 1   2   3
     array(10, 20, 30),    // 10  20  30
     array(100, 200, 300), // 100 200 300
);
function horizontalReverse($matrix) {
    $newMatrix = array();
    foreach ($matrix as $rowNum => $row) {
        $newMatrix[$rowNum] = array();
        foreach($row as $colNum => $column) {
            $newMatrix[$rowNum][sizeof($row) - $colNum - 1] = $matrix[$rowNum][$colNum];
        }
    }
    return $newMatrix;
}
function verticalReverse($matrix) {
    $newMatrix = array();
    foreach ($matrix as $rowNum => $row) {
        $newMatrix[sizeof($matrix) - $rowNum - 1] = array();
        foreach($row as $colNum => $column) {
            $newMatrix[sizeof($matrix) - $rowNum - 1][$colNum] = $matrix[$rowNum][$colNum];
        }
    }
    return $newMatrix;
}
```

Comment: а array_reverse разве нельзя использовать в паре?

Comment: @KoVadim, лабу не зачтут

Comment: @Fike вот и зря не зачтут.

Comment: после таких лаб я похоже и стал придумывать свои велосипеды, вместо поиска готовых решений...